# Output assigning in Maple inside for loop

Tags: maple

I am trying to define some solutions $x_k(t)$ inside a for loop in Maple.

I have tried

[image]

but I get an ugly output. I have also tried `x[k]:=t-> ...` but it makes an even uglier output.

If it wasn't inside a for loop I would have used

`x[k] := t -> (...) :
'x[k](t)' = x[k](t) ;`

to suppress the output from the assigning and make a nice output in the next line but it seems I cannot suppress only some of the lines inside a for loop?

Answer (score 3):

Suppress all output from the loop using a colon statement terminator on the `end do`. And then use `print` inside the loop to prettyprint exact that which you want shown.

```
for k from 1 to nops(sols) do
  x[k] := unapply(c[k]*exp(lambda[k]*t).v[k],t);
  print('x[k](t)' = x[k](t));
end do:
```

Comment: Thank you! But `print('x[k](t)' = ` outputs $x_k(t) =$ instead of replacing $k$ with $1$ and $2$, resp.

Comment: You are free to use `print( subs(_K=k,'x[_K](t)') = ...)` or build up that lhs howsoever you wish. I see that you''re now using `.` to keep Vector coefficients from being multiplied through the Vector (as I suggested as Answer to an earlier question of yours). But it's curious that you do not vote up or accept any of my answers to your questions, even when they clearly server to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

to suppress the output from the assigning and make a nice output in the next line but it you can use the tool step

```
> for k from 1 to nops (sols) steps 2 do
    x[k]=...
```

You will be able to suppress some of the lines inside of the loop.

Comment: I want to suppress one of the lines inside the for loop, not some of the elements in `sols`

Comment: I see, you should had specified it in your question. I'm asking around if ever somedy knows it but why don't you try to cut off your loop in two?

Comment: I could avoid using a loop; however, I want the code to handle $n$ number of solutions, but it seems I have to give up on creating a such generic solution